# Some questions about EDT and time difference

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

1. Introduction to my website

My website is for visitors in Korea(AKA Republic of Korea).
And the server for My website is in the United States of America.
And PHPMyAdmin displays `EDT` when it runs a query `SELECT @@ system_time_zone`.

2. Structure of my website

When I first uploaded my website to this server in October this year, I checked the DB time.
And it seemed that there was a time difference of 13 hours with Korea. So I added `3600 * 13` seconds to DB time(without setting timezone) as follows.

```
const Offset = 3600 * 13;
$SelectNow = $PDO->prepare('SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL '.Offset.' SECOND)');
$SelectNow->execute() or exit;
$DbNow = $SelectNow->fetchColumn();
```

My website takes `$DbNow` as above and uses it in various situations.
For example, in the posting situation, enter `$DbNow` in the datetime field of the `INSERT INTO` query as follows:

```
$WriteNote = $PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO table_note(my_datetime, my_contents) VALUES("'.$DbNow.'", :my_contents)');
$WriteNote->bindValue(':my_contents', $my_contents, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$WriteNote->execute();
```

3. The problem situation

One day in November of this year, when I wrote a post and checked the date field(`my_datetime`) of the post, I got an additional time difference of one hour with Korea.
Apparently, at the end of October, I corrected the time difference of `3600 * 13`. And then I confirmed that it matches the Korean time. However, in November, There is a time difference of one hour!

4. Guess the cause

It seems that US summer time is being applied to the DB server of my website. Did I guess right?

5. My question

1) How can I solve this time difference fundamentally?
Is it correct to convert DB time to `KST`?
Or is it the correct way to convert to `UTC` and then added `3600 * x` to `UTC`?

2) Even though the problem is resolved, some of the existing data in my DB has a time difference of one hour with Korean time.
What query do I use if I want to select the data with a time difference?
And how much more or subtract it from the data to get rid of the 1 hour time difference?

Comment: Always store time in UTC in database.
Display the respective time for different countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use UTC to store time in Database.
2. change your queries to insert with UTC datetimes.
3. Use external libraries to convert UTC to respective timezones.
   (below are the my personal recommendation.)
   There may be best of it.

   PHP : Carbon

   Javascript : Moment, moment timezone.
4. No, it takes timezone of Database server resides in.
5. little manual verification, or create a job to change all dates in UTC.

### Edit:

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

I mean you can create a script and run with cron job.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Did I get it right?
- When `INSERT INTO` a date in DB, use query with UTC timezone.
- In PHP, Use `carbon` to output the UTC date entered in the DB.
By the way, what does `create a job to change all dates in UTC 'mean?